# Datetime strftime formatting

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, strftime

I am taking my date column in my dataframe and making it a string in order to take off the time element when I write it to excel. For some reason I cant seem to write the date in the following format i need which is (10/2/2016). I can it to appear in this format (10/02/2016) but two issues arise - I need the day to be to one digit and not two and also is not in date order ( it seems to be sequencing on the month and not the year than month than day).

Here is my code:

```
df8 = df.set_index('DATE').resample('W-WED').apply(pd.DataFrame.tail, n=1)
df8.index= df8.index.droplevel(0)
df8 = df8.reset_index('DATE', drop=False)
df8['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df8['DATE']).apply(lambda x:x.date().strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Sample data (this is what is showing with the above formatting)

```
DATE        Distance (cm)
01/02/2013  206.85
01/04/2012  315.33
01/05/2011  219.46
01/06/2016  180.44
01/07/2015  168.55
01/08/2014  156.89
```

Comment: You need to post some sample data to help us out.

Comment: @Ted Petrou - I edited above so i could add in some sample data of what the code above was printing. Again, I am looking for the date to print as 01/2/2013, 01/4/2012, 01/05/2011 etc. It seems to also be no longer printing in date order but rather sequencing on the month, then the day and then the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`dt.day`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.Series.dt.day.html) instead of `%d` directive which automatically discards the leading zeros to give the desired formatted date strings as shown:

```
pd.to_datetime(df8['DATE']).map(lambda x: '{}/{}/{}'.format(x.month, x.day, x.year))
```

***Demo:***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(date=['2016/10/02', '2016/10/03', 
                             '2016/10/04', '2016/10/05', '2016/10/06']))

>>> pd.to_datetime(df['date']).map(lambda x: '{}/{}/{}'.format(x.month, x.day, x.year))
0    10/2/2016
1    10/3/2016
2    10/4/2016
3    10/5/2016
4    10/6/2016
Name: date, dtype: object
```

---

***EDIT based on sample data added:***

Inorder for it to impact only the days and not months, we must fill/pad the left side of the strings containing the `.month` attribute with 0's using [`str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) having a width parameter equal to 2, so that single digit months would be left padded with 0 and the double digit ones would be left unchanged.

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['DATE']).map(lambda x: '{}/{}/{}'.format(str(x.month).zfill(2), x.day, x.year))
0    01/2/2013
1    01/4/2012
2    01/5/2011
3    01/6/2016
4    01/7/2015
5    01/8/2014
Name: DATE, dtype: object
```

Comment: This is super helpful and was a great learning experience for me so thank you so very much. The only issue i am still having is i need the date column to be in order from earliest date to latest date. For example - 01/5/2011, 01/4/2012, 01/02/2013.. etc. Any way we can do this?

Comment: You're welcome! If you want to sort the date strings, it would be better that you convert your `object` *DATE* column to `datetime` first using `pd.to_datetime`. Sort the `DF` based on this column, like `df.sort_values(by=['DATE'], inplace=True)`. Now, your `DF` is in the ascending order of dates. After this, just use the syntax provided in my answer, but this time without the `to_datetime` part as they are already in `datetime64` type. Let me know how it goes from there.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://strftime.org/), you can make the day not zero-padded by using

```
Code      Meaning                                            Example
%m        Month as a zero-padded decimal number.             09
%-m       Month as a decimal number. (Platform specific)     9
```

So use `%-m` instead of `%m`

Comment: This doesn't work on Windows if I remember correctly.

Comment: @ayhan that explain the "platform specific" remark. Too bad. I'll still leave it here for future. non-windows, users

Comment: @Mathias711 - Yes, I tired this and it did not work and I am using windows.